# problem with ecryptfs-recover-private: mount(2) failed

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I'm in the process of moving my OS and data from one drive to another within the same computer. (I got a nice, new SSD.) My old home directory had an encrypted sub directory inside, and I'd like to access the encrypted directory from my new install. I'm trying to use `ecryptfs-recover-private`. However, I run into the following error.

```
$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /BLAH/.Private
INFO: Found [.Private/].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: 
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] 
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [BLAH] into the user session keyring
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.NcWkVmQ5].
```

I run into the same problem if I let `ecryptfs-recover-private` find the directory on its own or if I say no to the login passphrase but use the mount passphrase instead.

Thoughts?

(I realize there are several, similar questions on this site, but none seem to quite cover my situation.)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why this happens - maybe a screw-up in the kernel keyring when using the same LOGIN passphrase on your new setup as on the one you try to recover.

That said, adding the wrapped passphrase into the kernel keyring before trying to recover the filesystem works (be sure to use `sudo` on both commands below):

```
sudo ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring /BLAH/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /BLAH/.Private
```

Comment: `sudo` is required on the first command too (`ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring`) or else I get the following error! `Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs`

Comment: ...but unfortunately the 2nd command (`sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /BLAH/.Private`) still fails for me. :( `mount: /tmp/ecryptfs.aLkDeiWo: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.aLkDeiWo].`

Comment: This worked for me as well. Apparently, there's an open bug since 2018 with a hacky fix, but still not corrected : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/1769373

Answer (score 10):

So this simple command `ecryptfs-recover-private`, proved to be unreliable.
None of the metohd above worked for me, trying to move from *ecryptfs* to *LUKS* container.

What did work, was the **manual method** describe in [ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering_Your_Data_Manually)

In detail:

```
# sudo -i
# ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek 
Inserted auth tok with sig [aaaaaaaaaaaaa] into the user session keyring 
Inserted auth tok with sig [bbbbbbbbbbbbb] into the user session keyring  
# mkdir -p /mnt/new_mount_point  
# mount -t ecryptfs /mnt/old_mount_point/home/username/.Private /mnt/new_mount_point
```

- select 3  (use a passphrase key type, and use your recovered passphrase aka unwrapped-passphrase)
- select aes  (use the aes cipher)
- select 16  (use a 16 byte key)
- enable plaintext passthrough: n
- enable filename encryption: y

Comment: this worked for me but there is a final question after the filename encryption which asks for the FNEK signature to use, defaulting to the first auth tok in the output from `ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek`. I found I had to use the 2nd one instead.

Comment: This. The only method that works for me is to open the ubuntu community wiki linked above, and follow the instructions.

Comment: This worked for me! I followed the "Recovering Your Data Manually" instructions directly, as you indicated, here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering_Your_Data_Manually. Just remember that if you need to follow the section "Recovering Your Mount Passphrase" as well, you need to use `sudo`, even though they don't mention it. ie: instead of `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/username/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`, do `sudo ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/username/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` (notice also the slightly different path I used).

Comment: This solution appears to be incomplete as of today. There's at least one more question : `Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [XYZ]:` and I have no idea what this signature is... @Martin's solution (https://askubuntu.com/a/679565/924202) did it for me. :-)

Comment: In the result it "mounted" to a specified directory, but only file listing worked. Actual file data was unavailable (`No such file or directory` ) while filenames were visible.

Answer (score 6):

For me this worked, as discussed on [ecryptfs-mount-private fails to initialize ecryptfs keys](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1718658):

```
sudo keyctl link @u @s
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private .Private
```

Comment: Worked for me on NixOS. Also see https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/27574#issuecomment-457871746

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using debian testing and I recently needed to recover a file from the backup of my encrypted .Private folder. The backup is stored on my NAS. I experienced the same issue as you. Manually inserting the wrapped passphrase did not help and manually mounting the cifs filesystem (from my NAS) by root instead of creating the mount as my main user (to prevent right conflicts and whatever) did also not help.

However, after plainly rebooting my system, I could directly use the ecryptfs-recover-private command to mount the .Private folder, which itself was located on the cifs filesystem.

Though this is not explaining what's going wrong and it's one of the more frustrating hints you could get as a linux user:

reboot your system and try again :)

Comment: Ah, the oldest trick in the book! Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar errors after I renamed the previous (original) POSIX username to old_user (and ) and then created a new user with the original (previous username's) name.

To be able to mount the encrypted home directory from the old_user, I had to remake the symbolik links for .encryptfs and .Private in its folder (as they had poinded to /home/original_name/).

After that, the following command mounted the old home without any problem. /usr/bin/ecryptfs-recover-private /home/old_user/.Private

Comment: I think I have a very similar problem, but not sure how you did solve it... Do you mind having a  look at my new post? Thanks! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035424/ubuntu-18-04-mount-encrypted-disk

Comment: Hi, Matifou! What do you have in your syslog right after the attempt to do ecryptfs-recover-private /home/.ecryptfs/old_user/.Private ?

Comment: Hey! If you have problems with the key (see dmesg or syslog), e.g.
Could not find key with description: [XXX]
process_request_key_err: No key
Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [XXX]

then, try adding the passphrase manually:
Option "1" in /usr/bin/ecryptfs-manager

It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this problem not understanding why these simple commands did not work. 
I found, there are misleading links in .../home/.ecryptfs and .../home/.ecryptfs /username/.ecryptfs.

**EDIT**: the following solution needs to be confirmed.
The relink may not be mandatory, but the *parameters* given to `ecryptfs-recover-private` may be of source of the issue.

My solution was to relink with relative path the file .Private and .ecryptfs in /home/.ecryptfs/

To elaborate:

In my case the home user I wanted to read was in */mnt/sda5/home* and user was *guy*

```
    $ cd /mnt/sda5/home 

    $ ls -lag .ecryptfs/guy/
        drwxr-xr-x  4 guy    4096  .
        drwxr-xr-x  3 root   4096  ..
        drwx------ 16 guy    4096  .Private
        drwx------  2 guy    4096  .ecryptfs


    $ ls -lag .ecryptfs/guy/.ecryptfs/
        drwx------ 2 guy 4096 Jan 1 00:12 .
        drwxr-xr-x 4 guy 4096 Jan 1 00:11 ..
        -rw------- 1 guy   13 Jan 1 00:11 Private.mnt
        -rw------- 1 guy   34 Jan 1 00:11 Private.sig
        -rw-r--r-- 1 guy    0 Jan 1 00:11 auto-mount
        -rw-r--r-- 1 guy    0 Jan 1 00:11 auto-umount
        -rw------- 1 guy   58 Jan 1 00:12 wrapped-passphrase

    #This were the data are stored
```

If you list the files in the home directory, your have the following links (berefore my correction)

```
    $ ls -lag guy/
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     28 Jan 2 15:52 .Private  -> /home/guy/.Private
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     29 Jan 2 15:49 .ecryptfs -> /home/guy/.ecryptfs
```

so the files are linking to the current /home and user and not the ones you are trying to read, confusing you and the mounting commands.

After correction I implemented:

```
    $ ls -lag guy/
    dr-x------ 2 guy 4096 Jan 2 15:52 .
    drwxr-xr-x 6 root   4096 Jan 1 00:11 ..
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     28 Jan 2 15:52 .Private -> ../.ecryptfs/guy/.Private
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     29 Jan 2 15:49 .ecryptfs -> ../.ecryptfs/guy/.ecryptfs
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 guy   56 Jan 1 00:11 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 guy   52 Jan 1 00:11 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

My solution was to relink with relative path the file .Private and .ecryptfs

```
    $ cd /mnt/sda5/home 
    $ cd guy
    $ sudo unlink .Private
    $ sudo unlink .ecryptfs 
    $ sudo ln -sr ../.ecryptfs/guy/.Private
    $ sudo ln -sr ../.ecryptfs/guy/.ecryptfs
```

After you can mount manually the home directory manually or using

```
 cd /mnt/sda5/home 
 sudo ecryptfs-recover-private .ecryptfs/guy/.ecryptfs/.Private
```

(you will need your MOUNT passphrase - a serie of 32 characters-)